# Hubot coffeescript and JSON loops

Tags: javascript, json, coffeescript

I've never written coffeescript and have been trying to brute force my way through this for hours.

It's supposed to go grab JSON results for live scoring for myfantasyleague.com, but I can't seem to get the loops right.

The first loop gets the live scores, but the data returned only has a team id number, so I have to go match that id to another JSON query. I've tried about 100 permutations of where to put the i++, a break, a continue, a return, etc. but I'm just not getting it.

Here's what I have:

```
# Description:
#   Get MyFantasyLeague data
#
# Dependencies:
#   None
#
# Configuration:
#   HUBOT_MFL_LEAGUE_ID - set the league ID
#   HUBOT_MFL_LEAGUE_URL - set the league URL
#   HUBOT_MFL_LEAGUE_DATA_URL - Used to get the name to team id mapping
#
# Commands:
#   hubot: mfl scores
#
#
# Author:
#  Clayton Dukes <cdffl@remailed.ws>

leagueId = process.env.HUBOT_MFL_LEAGUE_ID
unless leagueId
  exit "You must enter your HUBOT_MFL_LEAGUE_ID in your environment variables"
leagueURL = process.env.HUBOT_MFL_LEAGUE_URL
unless leagueURL
  exit "You must enter your HUBOT_MFL_LEAGUE_URL in your environment variables"
teamData = process.env.HUBOT_MFL_LEAGUE_DATA_URL
unless teamData
  exit "You must enter your HUBOT_MFL_LEAGUE_DATA_URL in your environment variables"
module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.logger.debug "Using League URL: " + leagueURL
  robot.logger.debug "Using Team Data from " + leagueURL
  robot.respond /sc/i, (msg) ->
    response = "Live Scoring Results\n"
    robot.http(leagueURL)
        .header('Accept', 'application/json')
        .get() (err, res, body) ->
          if err
            return msg.send "Encountered an error :( #{err}"
          content = JSON.parse(body)
          matchups = content.liveScoring.matchup
          for game in matchups
            i=0
            #robot.logger.debug game['franchise']
            for team in game['franchise']
              id = team['id']
              playersCurrentlyPlaying = team['playersCurrentlyPlaying']
              gameSecondsRemaining = team['gameSecondsRemaining']
              score = team['score']
              robot.http(teamData)
                  .header('Accept', 'application/json')
                  .get() (err, res, body) ->
                    if err
                      return msg.send "Encountered an error :( #{err}"
                    data = JSON.parse(body)
                    teams = data.league.franchises
                    count = teams['franchise'].length
                    #robot.logger.debug "Found #{count} records"
                    while i<=count
                      name = teams['franchise'][i]['name']
                      teamId = teams['franchise'][i]['id']
                      if id is teamId
                        msg.send "ID = #{id}\n"
                        msg.send "TID = #{teamId}\n"
                        response += "Name: #{name}\n"
                        response += "Currently Playing: #{playersCurrentlyPlaying}\n"
                        response += "Game Seconds Remaining: #{gameSecondsRemaining}\n"
                        response += "Score: #{score}\n"
                        msg.send response
                        break
                      i++
```

Right now, this returns the same thing over and over until it bails:

```
[Tue Sep 15 2015 21:09:08 GMT-0400 (EDT)] DEBUG Sending to cdukes: ID = 0005

[Tue Sep 15 2015 21:09:08 GMT-0400 (EDT)] DEBUG Sending to cdukes: TID = 0005

[Tue Sep 15 2015 21:09:08 GMT-0400 (EDT)] DEBUG Sending to cdukes: Live Scoring Results
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78

[Tue Sep 15 2015 21:09:08 GMT-0400 (EDT)] DEBUG Sending to cdukes: ID = 0005

[Tue Sep 15 2015 21:09:08 GMT-0400 (EDT)] DEBUG Sending to cdukes: TID = 0005

[Tue Sep 15 2015 21:09:08 GMT-0400 (EDT)] DEBUG Sending to cdukes: Live Scoring Results
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78

[Tue Sep 15 2015 21:09:08 GMT-0400 (EDT)] DEBUG Sending to cdukes: ID = 0005

[Tue Sep 15 2015 21:09:08 GMT-0400 (EDT)] DEBUG Sending to cdukes: TID = 0005

[Tue Sep 15 2015 21:09:08 GMT-0400 (EDT)] DEBUG Sending to cdukes: Live Scoring Results
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78

[Tue Sep 15 2015 21:09:08 GMT-0400 (EDT)] DEBUG Sending to cdukes: ID = 0005

[Tue Sep 15 2015 21:09:08 GMT-0400 (EDT)] DEBUG Sending to cdukes: TID = 0005

[Tue Sep 15 2015 21:09:08 GMT-0400 (EDT)] DEBUG Sending to cdukes: Live Scoring Results
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78

[Tue Sep 15 2015 21:09:08 GMT-0400 (EDT)] DEBUG Sending to cdukes: ID = 0005

[Tue Sep 15 2015 21:09:08 GMT-0400 (EDT)] DEBUG Sending to cdukes: TID = 0005

[Tue Sep 15 2015 21:09:08 GMT-0400 (EDT)] DEBUG Sending to cdukes: Live Scoring Results
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78

[Tue Sep 15 2015 21:09:08 GMT-0400 (EDT)] DEBUG Sending to cdukes: ID = 0005

[Tue Sep 15 2015 21:09:08 GMT-0400 (EDT)] DEBUG Sending to cdukes: TID = 0005

[Tue Sep 15 2015 21:09:08 GMT-0400 (EDT)] DEBUG Sending to cdukes: Live Scoring Results
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78

[Tue Sep 15 2015 21:09:08 GMT-0400 (EDT)] DEBUG Sending to cdukes: ID = 0005

[Tue Sep 15 2015 21:09:08 GMT-0400 (EDT)] DEBUG Sending to cdukes: TID = 0005

[Tue Sep 15 2015 21:09:08 GMT-0400 (EDT)] DEBUG Sending to cdukes: Live Scoring Results
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78

[Tue Sep 15 2015 21:09:08 GMT-0400 (EDT)] DEBUG Sending to cdukes: ID = 0005

[Tue Sep 15 2015 21:09:08 GMT-0400 (EDT)] DEBUG Sending to cdukes: TID = 0005

[Tue Sep 15 2015 21:09:08 GMT-0400 (EDT)] DEBUG Sending to cdukes: Live Scoring Results
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78
Name: Blah
Currently Playing: 0
Game Seconds Remaining: 0
Score: 78

[Tue Sep 15 2015 21:09:09 GMT-0400 (EDT)] ERROR Received error {"code":-1,"msg":"slow down, too many messages..."}
[Tue Sep 15 2015 21:09:09 GMT-0400 (EDT)] ERROR undefined
[Tue Sep 15 2015 21:09:09 GMT-0400 (EDT)] ERROR Exiting in 1 second
```

Here are the two JSON data queries that get returned:

```
{
"liveScoring":{
"matchup":[
{
"franchise":[
{
"playersCurrentlyPlaying":"0",
"gameSecondsRemaining":"0",
"isHome":"0",
"players":{
},
"playersYetToPlay":"0",
"score":"129",
"id":"0001"
},
{
"playersCurrentlyPlaying":"0",
"gameSecondsRemaining":"0",
"isHome":"1",
"players":{
},
"playersYetToPlay":"0",
"score":"99",
"id":"0008"
}
]
},
{
"franchise":[
{
"playersCurrentlyPlaying":"0",
"gameSecondsRemaining":"0",
"isHome":"0",
"players":{
},
"playersYetToPlay":"0",
"score":"105",
"id":"0003"
},
{
"playersCurrentlyPlaying":"0",
"gameSecondsRemaining":"0",
"isHome":"1",
"players":{
},
"playersYetToPlay":"0",
"score":"98",
"id":"0007"
}
]
},
{
"franchise":[
{
"playersCurrentlyPlaying":"0",
"gameSecondsRemaining":"0",
"isHome":"0",
"players":{
},
"playersYetToPlay":"0",
"score":"125",
"id":"0002"
},
{
"playersCurrentlyPlaying":"0",
"gameSecondsRemaining":"0",
"isHome":"1",
"players":{
},
"playersYetToPlay":"0",
"score":"101",
"id":"0006"
}
]
},
{
"franchise":[
{
"playersCurrentlyPlaying":"0",
"gameSecondsRemaining":"0",
"isHome":"0",
"players":{
},
"playersYetToPlay":"0",
"score":"96",
"id":"0004"
},
{
"playersCurrentlyPlaying":"0",
"gameSecondsRemaining":"0",
"isHome":"1",
"players":{
},
"playersYetToPlay":"0",
"score":"78",
"id":"0005"
}
]
}
],
"week":"1"
},
"version":"1.0",
"encoding":"ISO-8859-1"
}
```

Next one is the query to get the team name from the given id in the first loop - I changed the team names, etc. below to protect the guilty :)

```
{
"version":"1.0",
"league":{
"currentWaiverType":"REVERSE",
"playerLimitUnit":"LEAGUE",
"taxiSquad":"0",
"survivorPool":"Yes",
"lastRegularSeasonWeek":"14",
"endWeek":"17",
"lockout":"No",
"minKeepers":"2",
"tiebreakerPosition":"*",
"injuredReserve":"0",
"franchises":{
"count":"8",
"franchise":[
{
"icon":"",
"abbrev":"CLAY",
"division":"00",
"name":"Team 1",
"waiverSortOrder":"8",
"iscommish":"1",
"logo":"",
"id":"0001"
},
{
"division":"01",
"name":"Team 2",
"id":"0002",
"waiverSortOrder":"7"
},
{
"logo":"",
"division":"00",
"name":"Team 3",
"id":"0003",
"waiverSortOrder":"6"
},
{
"icon":"",
"division":"01",
"name":"Team 4",
"id":"0004",
"waiverSortOrder":"5"
},
{
"division":"01",
"name":"Team 5",
"id":"0005",
"waiverSortOrder":"1"
},
{
"division":"01",
"name":"Team 6",
"id":"0006",
"waiverSortOrder":"4"
},
{
"logo":"",
"icon":"",
"abbrev":"BCB",
"division":"00",
"name":"Team 7",
"id":"0007",
"waiverSortOrder":"2"
},
{
"icon":"",
"division":"00",
"name":"Team 8",
"id":"0008",
"waiverSortOrder":"3"
}
]
},
"standingsSort":"PCT,PTS",
"draftPlayerPool":"Both",
"id":"36554",
"startWeek":"1",
"survivorPoolStartWeek":"1",
"survivorPoolEndWeek":"17",
"history":{
"league":[
{
"url":"http://football33.myfantasyleague.com/2015/home/36554",
"year":"2015"
},
{
"url":"http://football.myfantasyleague.com/2013/home/54662",
"year":"2013"
},
{
"url":"http://www.myfantasyleague.com/2014/home/12321",
"year":"2014"
}
]
},
"rosterSize":"16",
"name":"Some Name",
"rostersPerPlayer":"1",
"tiebreakerCount":"1",
"h2h":"YES",
"tiebreaker":"nonstarter",
"draftLimitHours":"1:00",
"maxKeepers":"2",
"divisions":{
"count":"2",
"division":[
{
"name":"East",
"id":"00"
},
{
"name":"West",
"id":"01"
}
]
},
"starters":{
"count":"9",
"position":[
{
"name":"QB",
"limit":"1"
},
{
"name":"RB",
"limit":"2-3"
},
{
"name":"WR",
"limit":"2-3"
},
{
"name":"TE",
"limit":"1"
},
{
"name":"PK",
"limit":"1"
},
{
"name":"Def",
"limit":"1"
}
],
"idp_starters":""
},
"baseURL":"http://football33.myfantasyleague.com",
"precision":"0",
"loadRosters":"email_draft"
},
"encoding":"ISO-8859-1"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll be better off by decomposing a little bit and then using list comprehensions, etc...  You can also use promises to cleanup the code and only load the data once instead of in a loop.

Something along these lines...

```
Promise = require('promise')

# configuration block (left out here)

jsonGet = (robot, url) ->
  new Promise (resolve, reject) ->
    robot.http(url)
      .header('Accept', 'application/json')
      .get() (err, res, body) ->
        if err
          robot.logger.error e
          reject err
        try
          resolve(JSON.parse(body));
        catch e
          robot.logger.error e
          reject e

teamName = (leagueData, team) ->
  return x.name for x in leagueData.league.franchises.franchise when x.id is team.id

sendLiveScoringResults = (msg, leagueData, liveScoringData) ->
  response = 'Live Scoring Results'
  for game in liveScoringData.liveScoring.matchup
    for team in game.franchise
      theTeamName = teamName(leagueData, team)
      response += "\nName: #{theTeamName}     Score: #{team.score}"
      ... (do whatever here)
  msg.send response


onFantasyScores = (robot, msg) ->
  jsonGet(robot, OWNER_INFORMATION)
    .then (leagueData) ->
      return { leagueData: leagueData }
    .then (data) ->
      jsonGet(robot, LIVE_SCORING_URL).then (liveScoringData) ->
        data.liveScoringData = liveScoringData
        data
    .then (data) ->
      sendLiveScoringResults msg, data.leagueData, data.liveScoringData
    .then null, (err) -> msg.send "An error occurred : #{err}"


module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.respond /fantasyscores/i, (msg) -> onFantasyScores(robot, msg)
```

Comment: Thanks @trever! It's now working and on github for all: https://github.com/claytondukes/myfflbot

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do something like this
instead of looping through the JSON

`teams = data.league.franchises
theTeam = teams.franchises.filter(teamId)`

that should give you an object with only the team data you want.